# Netbeans PHP. Run project throws error 404

Tags: php, apache, netbeans

I can´t run a php project from netbeans, can you help me looking for the error?

I've installed apache, and I have a folder like this: /var/www/html
If I create a file in that folder:

- sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php

With the next code:

`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

and then I run firefox in this link: localhost/info.php I can see the php version file, that's correct.

Then I create a project on Netbeans and I put it on the folder /var/www/html/Porject1, and I create a php file called test.php with the same phpinfo(); content like before, but when I Run Project I get an 404 Not Found (pointing to http://localhost/html/Project1/test.php), but if I delete html from that link, i see the phpinfo page.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated yourself, you put an `info.php` in the `/var/www/html` directory and browsed to it by `localhost/info.php` right?

Now you created a directory in the `/var/www/html`, named `project1`.
the full path to the `test.php` would be `/var/www/html/project1/test.php`.

As `/var/www/html/info.php` was equal to `localhost/info.php`,
`/var/www/html/project1/test.php` would be `localhost/project1/test.php`.
Why would you include the html directory? As you didnt do that with the `info.php` and that file was inside the `/var/www/html` directory.

`/var/www/html` is your webserver default root. It can be visited by using `localhost`. Everything in it, is accesible as `localhost/folder/folder/file.php`.

I.E.

`/var/www/html/project2/sample/folder/index.php` would be `localhost/project2/sample/folder/index/php`.

Netbeans trick thanks to [shashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5180017/shashanth):

In Netbeans right click on the project folder and select Properties. In Run Configurations set URL as http://localhost/project1/test.php.

Comment: A little update on your answer: In Netbeans right click on the project folder and select Properties. In Run Configurations set URL as `http://localhost/project1/test.php`.

Comment: @Shashanth I have no real experience with NetBeans. Thanks for the addition, i will add it to my answer!

Comment: Thank you both for your response. It helped me a lot, especially the answer of [tag:Shashant] that was the key to implement the solution of [tag:Clemenz]

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered. Glad to be of help.